# Excel VBA Copy/Paste Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to consolidate data from multiple worksheets into one, using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826484/6698914).

The difference is I only want a single column of data from each file copied so I have modified my code thus:

```
With wsMaster
     erow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row in column B
     '~~> Copy from the file you opened
     wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).Copy 'copy data in column A starting at row 2
     'to however long the data runs for
     '~~> Paste on your master sheet below last used row in column B
     .Range("B" & erow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

This works for the first iteration (it copies the first source file correctly) but when it gets to the second source file it throws an error "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method or Range class failed".

When in debug mode, I try to manually click and Ctrl+V the copied data, it says the size/shape of the ranges don't match.  HOWEVER - if I click in any cell at or above Row 2, it pastes the data it has copied in the macro, without complaining.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).Copy`

This line causes problem, please chenge this to

`wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Copy`

Answer (score 1):

When you are nested inside the `With wsMaster` it means all objects that you add the prefix `.` inside the `With` statement, are related to this object (`wsMaster` worksheet).

So your first place where you are trying to look for the last row is correct

```
erow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row in column B
```

But the second place, where you are trying to copy from a different sheet (from `wsTemp` worksheet), is not correct. The line below:

```
wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).Copy 'copy data in column A starting at row 2
```

Means that `.Rows.Count` is looking for count of rows in `wsMaster` sheet (and not `wsTemp`).

So you need to change that line to:

```
wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & wsTemp.Rows.Count).Copy
```

I prefer the following syntax to copy all occupied cells in Column "A":

```
wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & wsTemp.Cells(wsTemp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks Shai.  `wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & wsTemp.Rows.Count).Copy` didn't work.
But `wsTemp.Range("A2:A" & wsTemp.Cells(wsTemp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy` did.
I marked Chris's response as the answer as he was a bit earlier.

Comment: @EP it's ok, just for your knowledge, using xlCellTypeLastCell.Row might not be the most reliable way to get the last row